# Need some help on this symmetric matrix question

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

> Consider matrices of the form $M$ =
>   $$
>         \begin{bmatrix}
>         1 & s & 0 \\
>         t & 1 & s \\
>         0 & t & 1 \\
>         \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   where $s, t$ are both non-zero real numbers.

(a) Compute the determinant of M and deduce that M is invertible unless st = c where c
is a constant that you should determine.

**Answer**

c = 1/2, st /= 1/2

(b) Why can we deduce from (a) that if $st = c$ then zero is an eigenvalue of $M$? Find a corresponding eigenvector in the case that $st = c$.

**Answer**

eigenvector = $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -s  \\
        1  \\
        -t  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

(c) Show that $λ = 1$ is always an eigenvalue of M and find a corresponding eigenvector.

**Answer**

eigenvector = $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        s  \\
        0  \\
        -t  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

(d) Suppose now that $s = t =
√
c$ where $c$ is as above. Use properties of real symmetric
matrices to find a third eigenvector of $M$ and hence write down an orthogonal
diagonalization of $M$

**What I've got**

Two unit vectors,$$        
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1/2  \\
        1/(\sqrt 2)  \\
        -1/2  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
    1/(\sqrt 2)  \\
    0  \\
    -1/(\sqrt 2)  \\
    \end{bmatrix}

orthogonal unit vector = $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1/2  \\
    1/(\sqrt 2)  \\
    1/2  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

This is where I get confused. The marking scheme says "Calculating, we find that M applied to this vector is twice the vector and so the eignevalue is 2." But when I tried to calculated the eigenvalue it was clearly incorrect but I cant figure out what went wrong. I did the matrix M
$$ 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & (\sqrt 2) & 0 \\
    (\sqrt 2)& 1 & (\sqrt 2)\\
    0 & (\sqrt 2)& 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
Multiplied by the orthogonal unit vector, which gave me $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    3/2  \\
    (\sqrt 2) + 1  \\
    3/2  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Would someone be able to do a step by step answer for d) because the marking scheme isn't very clear.

Comment: Sorry, added the answers for a), b) and c) now

Comment: Oh that's a mistake, sorry about that!

Comment: Please show us your work for (d) and the answer in the marking scheme.

Comment: Added answer for d)

Comment: You mistake was an incorrect substitution for $s$ and $t$ in $M$. Try multiplying it by the first eigenvector—you won’t get get 0.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Should it be $1/(\sqrt 2)$ instead of $(\sqrt 2)$